# Disable search field in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar

[image]

Is there a way to disable only the search field if the scope title is 'All', but enable it when you click on the other scope titles?

I try setting the `searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` but it disables the scope title bar as well. Therefore, I'm unable to interactive with the scope titles to reenable the search field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no public API to enable or disable the text field in the search bar. However, you have a solution.

When the "All" scope button is selected, resign the search bar as the first responder. That should dismiss the keyboard. Set the `text` property to the empty string.

Implement the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` delegate method. Return `false` if the "All" scope button is selected, `true` for the others. This will prevent the search field from becoming active once "All" has been selected.

Optionally you can update the search bar's `prompt` as needed to help the user understand why nothing happens when they try to type into the search bar while "All" is selected.